# Debug c# program located in specific folder

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I have a program that wrapping A UI application
I need to add the option to run the other UI program which located in different folder

Program A is .net-framework project which located in folder `C:\Test`

Program B is .net core project which located in `C:\Test\ProgramB`

Program A Main code:

```
[STAThread]
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        return ProgramB.Program.Main(args);  
    }
```

I need to allow debugging on starting Program B through Program A

once i start debugging i see assembly loading exceptions, since program B have different dependencies on its folder.

1. is it possible to load the .Net core dll files from .net-framework project?
2. How can i load the assemblies correctly and allow debugging this way?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to invoke a .NET Core assembly (an EXE, but one you don't want to run in a separate process) from.a .NET Framework app? It may be a lost cause. Can you better explain what you are trying to do, and why?

Comment: What IDE are you using to code in?

Comment: 1. I use Visual studio.
2. the reason i do it since this is a project that let clients integrate with our product, and in order to not break API's we left the dotnet framework app to the use of our clients, and we want to control the target UI or program will be used according to clients usage

Comment: @MichaelGabbay - When responding to comments do them one line at a time and use the `@` symbol to notify who you're responding to. Then we will know to look at your comment. I'd suggest deleting and reposting your comment as two.

Comment: Does thing thing run outside the debugger, and the only problem you are having is running it in the debugger? You can specify what app should be run to start up your code for debugging (project properties -> debug). Otherwise, you should consider having the the ProjectB not be an EXE with a Main. Instead make a _".NET Standard"_ DLL with an entry point you specify. If you want to be able to run it standalone, provide a minimal exe that loads and runs it

Comment: Note that your code does not run ProgramB as a separate process, but loads the assemby into the running process (ProgramA) and runs it there. To start as a new process, use Process.Start.

Comment: @Flydog57 this is what i want to do. the minimal exe is 'ProgramA' and the ProgramB is a dll with Main entry point.
my problem is that the dll sits in different folder than ProgramA's output and being copied and it is not part of the solution. and copied on build event since the dependencies of ProgramA and ProgramB are different.
My question is how to manipulate the dll loading from the target folder of ProgramA to load the other folder dll files

Comment: @KlausGütter indeed, i do want it to run on the same process but the ProgramB is resource and i don't have a project reference inside the solution

Comment: @Enigmativity I use Visual studio 2022.

Comment: @MichaelGabbay: did my answer help? If so consider upvoting and/or accepting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your problem, you want to debug ProjectB, but in order to get it to run, you need to run ProgramA.

If this is correct, try the following:

1. In the Solution Explorer, make ProjectB be the startup project (right-click, Set as startup project)
2. Right click on the ProjectB node and choose Properties
3. Choose the Debug "tab" in the Properties page
4. Set the exectable path and name for ProgramA, any command line arguments, etc. *(the UI varies between Framework and Core projects, but the essence is the same)*
5. Put a breakpoint on the main entry point to ProjectB (`Main` in this case, I believe)
6. Press `F5`

At that point, your ProjectB should start up by starting ProgramA. This is the typical way to debug plug-in DLLs